# Returning mysql data using xamarin android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm a little new to this side of stuff.
I have a app with login,
I have a button on my app,and when this button is pressed. The user is shown a text box to enter a name,
When a user enters a name this information is loaded to a database
This works so far, but I'm stuck with the next bit,
I need to generate check boxes based on the database information, for example.

If I added a text called arrange meeting
I need this to get info from the database, and then I need the code to generate check boxes next to all the info from that table.

For example
(Checkbox) arrange meeting
(Checkbox) make call

The idea is a button is pressed so a task can be added this task will cone with a checkbox to tick when completed.

Its importent to know I'm running the sql within the app, I know this is a security issue, but the app will nit be public, and it would be edited at a later date to use web apis

Comment: You just need to get the data from your mysql,then bind them to the CheckBox which defined in your xaml.

Comment: Do you have an example of this please.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot for the effect you want ?

Comment: I just want check boxes based on what's in the database table so if there ls 4 names in the database table then 4 name will show with a tick box next to each name

Comment: So basically when a user enters text, then clicks done (already setup) then the name saves ti database, I then need this name to read from the database and return it but with a checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample.Is it the effect you want?

define **CheckContentView**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CheckContentView : ContentView
{
    public CheckContentView(string[] data) //the parameter is the data you get from the database
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(sss, data);
    }
}
```

CheckContentView.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NewForms.CheckContentView">
   <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout x:Name="sss" Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}">
                 
                    </Label>
                    <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
      </StackLayout>
   </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

then in your page.cs:

```
public partial class YourPage: ContentPage
{
    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string[] s = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckContentView checkContentView = new CheckContentView(s);
        stacklayout.Children.Add(checkContentView);
    }
}
```

YourPage.xaml:

```
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
      
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I managed to do this a different way but there a little bug I cant find. I was hoping someone can help so I'll explain what I did, in my design tab i added an Id to my linear view, I posted my code here https://pastebin.com/SDS6etss   the issue now is it shows the result like I wanted but the result is duplicated many times so instead of 3 from the db its adding loads. For example I have boo in the db the result comes back boo, boo, boo what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can anyone help to see where I went wrong with my method in the link i posted,  it returns all results as wanted, but there duplicated.